# Where can I ask questions about setting up an open source web application?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which Stack Exchange site should I post questions and issues about installing open source web applications?

For example I have an issue with FocusOPEN the web based digital assessment management tool in terms of database connection that does not work.

Is Stack Overflow the right place?

Comment: What kind of question?

Comment: For example I have an issue with FocusOPEN the web based digital assessment management tool in terms of database connection that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). It is prohibited to ask about common CMS systems that have an own SE site, but FoxusOPEN is not on the list (also not really a CMS I guess).

> Questions here are commonly about search engine optimization (SEO), domains, and web-hosting.

Very specific database problems should be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you. Not really a CMS but very close. Problem has been solved meanwhile thank you. But it is good to know where to ask for the next time. Why would you not recommend stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming issues, and I didn't think you'd involved with the code yourself.

Comment: This is true. I was not sure about that Stackoverflow is only for programming issues.

Comment: It is best to read the on-topic page in every SE page for that. Here is the one for SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. It shows only software *development* related topics.